# Need to add tuple in case class variable under condition

Tags: scala, case-class

I have a case class as

```
case class Attendance(List(name,totalDay))
```

and i have three variable

```
val ana = 0
val mario = 33
val romero = 11
```

I have to create the object of attendance class such as they have 
name and attendance only if attendance is greater than zero like for above i should have

```
Attendance((Mario,33),(Romero,12))
```

Comment: Just a quick tip: To avoid hurting your eyes, name variables / vals using lower-camel-case (e.g. `myVariable`) and types (like case classes) using upper-camel-case (e.g. `MyCaseClass`).

Answer (score 5):

Your code is not only very far from what's considered best practice in Scala in terms of variable and class naming, but also has inconsistencies:

At first, you show the code snippet:

```
// --- WRONG --- //
val Ana = 0
val Mario = 33
val Romero = 11
```

And then you show the code snippet

```
// --- WRONG --- //
Attendance((Mario,33),(Romero,12))
```

The problem is that in this situation, `(Mario, 33)` just means `(33, 33)`, because `Mario` is a variable that you assigned to be `33`. What you should do instead is:

```
val ana = ("Ana", 0)
val mario = ("Mario", 33)
val romero = ("Romero", 11)
```

Another inconsistency is

```
// --- WRONG --- //
case class attendance(List(name,totalDay))
```

This would not compile. When writing `List(name, totalDay)` you define a `List` containing two elements, `name` and `totalDay`. These elements are not defined in your example.

What you want to do instead is:

```
case class Attendance(attendees: List[(String, Int)])
```

What does `attendees: List[(String, Int)]` mean?

It means that you define a parameter to your case class `Attendance`,
and this parameter is called `attendees`, and is of type `List[(String, Int)]` (speak: "*A list of tuples, each consisting of a string and an integer*")

Then you can use it:

```
val listOfAttendees: List[(String, Int)] = ??? // Not implemented yet
val attendance = Attendance(listOfAttendees)
```

But how do you make `listOfAttendees`?

The answer is `filter`:

```
val allAttendees = List(ana, mario, romero)
val filteredAttendees = allAttendees.filter {
   case (name, days) => days > 0
}
```

Put it all together:

```
val ana = ("Ana", 0)
val mario = ("Mario", 33)
val romero = ("Romero", 11)

case class Attendance(attendees: List[(String, Int)])

val allAttendees = List(ana, mario, romero)

val filteredAttendees = allAttendees.filter {
   case (name, days) => days > 0
}

val attendance = Attendance(filteredAttendees)
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/xgdPyRJ/0)

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you help, Sorry for the inconsistency in my code. As i wrote pseudo code (will keep a note of writing better one if must). However your code worked like charms, Thanks a lot again

Comment: @devD Can you accept the answer if it was helpful to you?

Comment: @devD Please accept the answer if it is helpful to you.